# Lower ROM minimum brightness

Tags: root-access, screen-brightness

On my rooted stock ROM LG G2 D802 KK 4.4.2 minimum brightness is actually 50 (not 0) on a scale from 0 to 255.

Here is my `dumpsys power`

```
POWER MANAGER (dumpsys power)


Settings and Configuration:
...
  mScreenBrightnessSettingMinimum=50
  mScreenBrightnessSettingMaximum=255
  mScreenBrightnessSettingDefault=102
...

Display Controller Configuration:
  mScreenBrightnessDimConfig=50
  mScreenBrightnessRangeMinimum=50
  mScreenBrightnessRangeMaximum=255
```

I tried editing `build.prop`, adding `ro.lcd_min_brightness=20` but no luck, if I edit `/sys/class/backlight/brightness` to a value lower than 50 brightness stays at default minimum even if brightness slider is over minimum.

Where should I look for this hardcoded 50 minimum value? Framework.apk, kernel, SystemUI.apk...?

Answer (score 0):

If I edit my brightness value manually, it won't go below the minimum, and I have never figured out why. If I use the app brightness tweak however, I can lower it all the way to one. You can find the app on xda labs, I hope it's compatable with jellybean. I also hope this helps you.